# Extracting data from jpeg graph and making new one

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I extracted data from this graph:
[image]

and got values like:

3,646E+003  5,077E+000

2,910E+004  5,077E+000

5,819E+004  5,100E+000....

When I try to plot only right column in excel I am getting the same plot, but with opposite axis. What I am doing wrong? How can I get the same graph?
[image]

Edit: [image]

Comment: The y axis on the first graph, is it a count of each instance?

Comment: No it is not. It is frequency in Hz, and the x axis are values of capacity F.

Answer (score 0):

Use an XY scatter chart with one set of numbers for the Y values and the other set of numbers for the X values. Make sure both sets of values are numbers. If even one of the values is text, the scatter chart will turn the whole axis into a numbered category from 1 to n.

Format the numbers for each axis as desired.

Comment: Thanks! Now it looks much better(see edit), but can you tell how excatly can I fix axis, if I clicked on format axis I dont see where excatly I can change them.

Comment: The exact steps depend on your version of Excel. In the format dialog for the axis there is a section for number.